# php cli not working, pdo not found

Tags: php, nginx, pdo

I run this command to debug why php cli not working:

```
php -n MYPHPFILE.php
```

And get this:

```
Fatal error: Class 'PDO' not found in example-file.php on line 59
```

I have checked PDO extension and its already correct installed. Im running nginx, php5 fpm server.

Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: Are you using namespaces in your app?

Comment: Are you sure that cli version is the same of apache version?

Comment: How can i check versions? Im using nginx with php5-fpm.
And im running a Magento website

Comment: Why are you using the `-n` parameter?

Comment: How do you know that the PDO lib is installed properly?  try running 'php -i  | grep PDO ' from the command line

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `-n` switch means (quoted from `php --help`):

> No php.ini file will be used

When PHP is built, it is usually configured with the option `--with-config-file-scan-dir=target`. This causes PHP to scan `target` upon startup for additional ini files, `target` might be something like `/etc/php.d`. This is usually the mechanism by which individual extensions are loaded.

The help text omits to mention that `-n` also stops `target` being scanned, what it [will soon](http://git.php.net/?p=php-src.git;a=commit;h=4808d9689a8791a25554b09f8e68726216a52b78) say is:

> No configuration (ini) files will be used

This results in the configuration line that loads `PDO` (`extension=pdo.so`) not being used, either because it is in `php.ini` or because it is in another ini file inside the scan directory.

Remove the `-n` switch.

Comment: I had to add the `-c` flag to tell the cli from where to load the php.ini :

`php -c /my_project/php.ini ` then it worked !